# Visual Studio 2010 "Smudging"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

After purchasing a new monitor and setting up a dual monitor display, VS 2010 is smudging. I'm not really sure how to describe it, but it is really annoying. See here:

[image]

[image]

I've tried reinstalling VS, but no luck. My video card is a ATI Radeon HD 5770, and I'm using Catalyst Control Center drivers for it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's incredibly weird - so weird it almost looks fake.  I'm curious to see if anybody knows what's wrong.

Comment: I can assure you that this is not fake. Here are some full screens:
http://imgur.com/3uvDH
http://imgur.com/4FO0f

Comment: Obviously, the first big question is whether anything else "smudges."  Please post screencaps of Photoshop, Word, whatever else you have.

Comment: Nope, tried Photoshop, Mozilla, Minecraft and BS Player. They all seem to work fine.
http://i.imgur.com/P13hZ.png

Comment: No, it's not screenshots of *any* other application that are going to be informative. This is almost certainly something related to **WPF**. Do you have any other WPF applications on your computer? Or, you could try creating a simple one in Visual Studio, and see if it "smudges". It's probably a video driver issue; I think I might have seen this reported somewhere for VS already, but I can't think of where or what the fix was.

Comment: Sorry if my comment came across as accusatory - that's just a strange graphical artifact.  Glad to see it's fixed now.

Comment: I love the name for your D drive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This bug report on Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/555577/faded-blurry-text-still-not-fixed-in-visual-studio-2010-ultimate) suggests symptoms similar to those you describe.

The simple fix might be to [turn off the "rich client visual experience"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2023207). To do that, follow these steps:

1. From the "Tools" menu, select "Options".
2. Expand the "Environment" category, and select "General".
3. Uncheck the box labeled "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance".
4. Uncheck the box labeled "Enable rich client visual experience".
5. You might also try turning off "Use hardware graphics acceleration if available".
6. Click OK.

[image: Adjusting relevant settings in VS Options dialog]

I realize this isn't a particularly good long-term solution, but it might help to make Visual Studio usable for you. There are still some problems like this that crop up since they switched the user interface to WPF. It's really difficult to justify switching client applications to WPF if they can't get it quite right in their flagship development software.

Of course, a lot of things *were* significantly improved from the beta versions to the RTM—fonts in the editor window [were the big one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/11/wpf-text-clarity-improvements.aspx), although they're still not exactly the same in VS 2010 as they were in previous versions. It appears that certain client configurations can still cause strange bugs like this one to appear. For what it's worth, I've never personally experienced this on any of the several different machines I run VS on.

Comment: Thanks so much, turning off hardware acceleration fixed it for me.

Comment: Fantastic answer to what seemed like a phony question.  I'm impressed!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and did your recommendations. 
Here is my screenshot of the behavior
[image]

But the problem still there after applying what Cody said.
I could fix the problem uninstalling "LogMeIn Mirror Driver" which caused this lack of refresh (I had to select some code to force a good refresh).

Hope this helps if you have same problem.
The behavior still the same in Visual Studio 2013.